# Sudoku solver in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sudoku

I decided to learn JavaScript and what better way than wrestling with a Sudoku solver. I'm guessing there are (many?) optimizations that I missed. I'm thinking of adding a generator also, but this for another time. Thoughts?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="form">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" size="1" name="sud[]"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" size="2" onclick="test();">Solve</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    function solve(matrix) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
          //check for legitimate values
          if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
            continue;
          }
          for (var k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
            if (insert(matrix, i, j, k) == true) {
              matrix[i][j] = k;
              b = solve(matrix);
              if (b == true) {
                return true;
              }
              matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;

    }

    function insert(matrix, i, j, k)
      //check column and rows
      {
        for (var a = 0; a <= 8; a++) {
          if (a != i && matrix[a][j] == k) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        for (var a = 0; a <= 8; a++) {
          if (a != j && matrix[i][a] == k) {
            return false;
          }
        }

        //check the 3 by 3 squares
        var y = Math.floor((i / 3)) * 3;
        var x = Math.floor((j / 3)) * 3;
        for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
          for (var b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
            if (a != i && b != j && matrix[y + a][x + b] == k) {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        return true;
      }




    function test() {


      var holder = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 81; i++) {

        //  document.form[i].value  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;


        //get the form values

        holder[i] = (document.form[i].value);


        var matrix = [],
          j, k;

        // from 1 dimensional to matrix

        for (j = 0, k = -1; j < holder.length; j++) {
          if (j % 9 === 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
          }

          matrix[k].push(holder[j]);
        }

      }


      solve(matrix);

      var solved = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {


          solved.push(matrix[i][j]);
          //make a one dimensional array from  solved matrix;
        }
      }

      for (var z = 0; z < solved.length; z++) {



        document.form[z].value = solved[z];
        //display the solved sudoku numbers 
      }

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I used [jshint](http://jshint.com/) and created a function to generate the table HTML content.

I also grouped the variable declarations (not "all to the top" as [jslint](https://jslinterrors.com/move-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-function)) and simplified the conditional checks.

In the `solve` function, I inverted the check in order to remove the `continue` statement. In my opinion this makes the code easier to read ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728757/why-are-continue-statements-bad-in-javascript)).

The click event is using an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in order to remove JS from HTML.

All DOM selection is made through [query selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

```js
function solve(matrix) {
  var i, j, b, k;
  for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
      //check for legitimate values
      if (!matrix[i][j]) {
        for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
          if (insert(matrix, i, j, k)) {
            matrix[i][j] = k;
            b = solve(matrix);
            if (b) { return true; }
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function insert(matrix, i, j, k) {
  //check column and rows
  var a, b;
  for (a = 0; a <= 8; a++) {
    if (a != i && matrix[a][j] == k) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  for (a = 0; a <= 8; a++) {
    if (a != j && matrix[i][a] == k) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  //check the 3 by 3 squares
  var y = Math.floor((i / 3)) * 3,
      x = Math.floor((j / 3)) * 3;
  for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
      if (a != i && b != j && matrix[y + a][x + b] == k) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function test() {
  var form = document.querySelector('form#sudoku'),
      matrix,
      holder = [],
      i, j, k, z;
  for (i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    //get the form values
    holder[i] = form[i].value;
    matrix = [];
    k = -1;
    // from 1 dimensional to matrix
    for (j = 0; j < holder.length; j++) {
      if (j % 9 === 0) {
        k++;
        matrix[k] = [];        
      }
      matrix[k].push(holder[j]);
    }
  }

  solve(matrix);

  //display the solved sudoku numbers
  z = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {      
      //display the solved sudoku numbers
      form[z].value = matrix[i][j];
      z++;
    }
  }
}

function populateTable() {
  var i, j, tr, td, input,
      table = document.querySelector('form#sudoku table'),
      tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {            
      td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'text';
      input.size = 1;
      td.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('input[value=Solve]')
    .addEventListener('click', test);
}

populateTable();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Sudoku">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Sudoku</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="sudoku">
      <table></table>
      <input type="button" value="Solve">
    </form>
    <!-- script src="sudoku.js" type="text/javascript" -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  We usually prefer more review of the code.  Why is the new code preferable to the old code?

Comment: hey, thx for the response. I'll update the answer.